# A website from a major grocery chain seems to be stopping my webscraper from collecting the information on the webpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir

I'm trying to scrape from information from https://www.kroger.com/cl/coupons/ using Watir but when I do I get the message "Access Denied You don't have permission to access "http://www.smithsfoodanddrug.com/cl/coupons/" on this server. Reference #18.f6ddedcc.1546972451.30a85f8f "

I've looked at other websites that also might have the information I'm looking for but it doesn't seem to be as up to date.

```
def save
    require 'watir'

    @browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, headless: true
    @browser.goto "https://www.smithsfoodanddrug.com/cl/coupons/"
    sleep 5
    @divs = @browser.divs
    @spans = @browser.spans
    @body = @browser.body
end
```

My expected result is that I would be seeing the coupons from the webpage that you would see if you were to visit the website on a normal browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like they are blocking automated access to their site. You can't even curl their site.

Comment: Wow, did you get that from "Access Denied" ? Also how exactly is curl supposed to  do better than Watir ?